# Typedef of Numeric Types

Tags: c++, typedef

I am using a large physics package, Geant4, for running simulations.  There are a number of typedefs defined in the language, and used exclusively throughout the package.

```
typedef double G4double;
typedef float G4float;
typedef int G4int;
typedef bool G4bool;
typedef long G4long;
```

I understand the use of typedefs for exposing numeric types as domain-specific types, as this improves readability and allows the typedef to be changed at a later point, if needed.  In this case, though, the typedefs are so broad that they do not serve that purpose.

I have also heard of typedefs are being used to ensure a consistent bitsize of each type, as `sizeof(int)` is not guaranteed by the standard.  This cannot be in this case, as these typedefs are always present, rather than being generated by a script after checking the size of the type in question.

What other purposes might there be that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries like to do this to maintain consistency within their code.  All types they use (even primitives) start with `G4`.

In theory you could redefine these on specific platforms if the size of some primitive type causes a problem.

Personally, I've never heard of someone needing to do such.  Where specific sizes are required, they're generally used in the first place.  But that doesn't mean it hasn't happened.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for me to state why this particular library did this. However, I have done similar in my library, and I can give a few reasons, some of which you already mentioned:

1. It allows you to enhance cross-platform portability without having `xintxx_t` types floating around.
2. It allows you to swap out types - possibly at build time. An example of this is if you wanted to have a 3D engine that supported both single and double float precision, you might declare `typedef float MyLibraryFloat;` or `typedef double MyLibraryFloat;` triggered by a define macro.
3. It can help library abstraction. Say you have a library that acts as the front end to several different libraries with (mostly) compatible APIs. Abstracting the types can help this, although it is often not as simple as a `typedef` in this case.

I think the best reason is the second. It is definitely the most useful if you are dealing with a situation where your types might change based on compiler settings. However, the first is common, especially in older C programs. OpenGL/GLUT does abstraction of types for size safety.